# Date List Increment Method in Java

Tags: java, list, date

Okay, So here is the question, I am trying to make a method, which helps me put all the dates from date A to date B in a list and place the day type in front of it for example:
Date A- 01 JAN 2013 Date B-03 JAN 2013

The result should be like this

01-01-2013 Tuesday

02-01-2013 Wednesday

03-01-2013 Thursday

And this should be either in a Map/List.

I tired the following approach to first at least have the dates in the list, but got a Java Out of Heap Space Error.

```
public static List<ShiftDate> createShiftDate() {
        String startDate = "2013-01-01";

        String lastDate = "2013-01-28";
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        List<ShiftDate> shiftDateList = new ArrayList<ShiftDate>();
        ShiftDate shiftDate = new ShiftDate();

        try {
            Date startDate1 = formatter.parse(startDate);
            Date endDate1 = formatter.parse(lastDate);
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date newDate = startDate1;

            while (newDate.compareTo(endDate1) < 0) {
                c.setTime(newDate);
                c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                shiftDate.setDateString(c.getTime().toString());
                shiftDateList.add(shiftDate);
            }

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (ShiftDate shiftDate1 : shiftDateList) {
            System.out.println(shiftDate1);
        }
        return shiftDateList;
    }
```

Comment: You don't seem to be changing newDate or endDate1, which makes the while loop run infinitely.

Comment: @Henrik Can you please suggest the correction, because i tried updating the value of newDate and then adding that to the list, but that didn't work

Comment: Not only that, you only have 1 `ShiftDate` that gets added again and again to your list.

Comment: @D3X Some general advice: Try using a debugger to step through your program. This allows you to inspect its variables, and make it easier to spot errors like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You are not updating the loop condition variable (`newDate`). It should look like this:

   ```
       while (newDate.compareTo(endDate1) < 0) {
           c.setTime(newDate);
           c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
           newDate = c.getTime();
           shiftDate.setDateString(c.getTime().toString());
           shiftDateList.add(shiftDate);
       }
   ```
2. Other problems: you have the formatter set to dd-MM-yyyy patter, but the actual dates are in yyyy-MM-dd pattern.
3. Also, you'll need to create a new instance of ShiftDate each time or else each time. Or else you will end up with the entire listing containing the same (last updated) date value.

   ```
       while (newDate.compareTo(endDate1) < 0) {
           c.setTime(newDate);
           c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
           newDate = c.getTime();
           shiftDate = new ShiftDate();
           shiftDate.setDateString(c.getTime().toString());
           shiftDateList.add(shiftDate);
       }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here, you didn't increase `newDate` value, so the loop never ends:

```
while (newDate.compareTo(endDate1) < 0) {
                c.setTime(newDate);
                c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                shiftDate.setDateString(c.getTime().toString());
                shiftDateList.add(shiftDate);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
    String startDate = "2013-01-01";
    String lastDate = "2013-01-28";
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Calendar st=Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar lt=Calendar.getInstance();
    st.setTime(simpleDateFormat.parse(startDate));
    lt.setTime(simpleDateFormat.parse(lastDate));
    List<Date> list=new ArrayList<>();
    for (Date date = st.getTime(); !st.after(lt); st.add(Calendar.DATE, 1), 
                                                           date = st.getTime())
    {
       list.add(date);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are correct.

## Time zone

Well, mostly correct… except that all the answers and the question ignore the question of time zones which defines what a day means.

## Joda-Time

Here's the same kind of code in [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time), and address time zone.

Couple notes:

- In Joda-Time a DateTime truly knows its assigned time zone, whereas a java.util.Date does not.
- Notice the call to `withTimeAtStartOfDay` to get first moment of the day. That is usually 00:00:00 but not always.
- You should generally specify a [time zone](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html) rather than rely on default.
  This example arbitrarily chose the [Kolkata time zone](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=54) (formerly known as Calcutta, India).
- You should generally specify a [Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) rather than rely on default.
  Notice the call to `withLocale` as an example localizing to French, perhaps for [Puducherry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puducherry).

### Sample Code

```
// You might want to store the date times, and then create strings later as output. I'll show both.
java.util.List<DateTime> dateTimes = new java.util.ArrayList<DateTime>(3);
java.util.List<String> dateTimeStrings = new java.util.ArrayList<String>(3);

DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" );
DateTime start = new DateTime( 2014, 1, 1 , 2, 3, 4, timeZone ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "dd-MM-yyyy EEEE" ).withLocale( Locale.FRENCH );
for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
    DateTime nextDateTime = start.plusDays( i );
    dateTimes.add( nextDateTime );
    dateTimeStrings.add( formatter.print( nextDateTime ) );
}
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "dateTimes: " + dateTimes );
System.out.println( "dateTimeStrings: " + dateTimeStrings );
```

When run…

```
dateTimes: [2014-01-01T00:00:00.000+05:30, 2014-01-02T00:00:00.000+05:30, 2014-01-03T00:00:00.000+05:30]
dateTimeStrings: [01-01-2014 mercredi, 02-01-2014 jeudi, 03-01-2014 vendredi]
```

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later supplants Joda-Time as well as the troublesome old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java.

The [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class supports a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

The handy [`DayOfWeek`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum can generate a localized display name of the day of week. The [`TextStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/TextStyle.html) says how long or abbreviated you want the display name.

Your input strings are in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. They can be parsed directly by the `LocalDate` class as all the java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing and generating Strings that represent date-time values.

The best practice generally in handling spans of time is Half-Open, where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So we test using [`isBefore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#isBefore-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate-) in the loop below.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse( "2013-01-01" );
LocalDate stop = LocalDate.parse( "2013-01-28" );

List<String> outputs = new ArrayList<>();
LocalDate localDate = start ;
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH;  // Or Locale.US Locale.UK etc.
while ( localDate.isBefore( stop ) ) {
    String displayName = localDate.getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , locale );
    String localDateString = localDate.toString();
    String output = localDateString + " " + displayName;
    outputs.add( output );

    // Set up next loop.
    localDate = localDate.plusDays( 1 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently developed [Lamma date](http://lamma.io) library which is designed for this use case. With Lamma, this problem can be solved like this:

```
public static List<Date> createShiftDate() {
    List<Date> dates = Dates.from(2013, 1, 1).to(2013, 1, 28).build();

    for (Date date: dates) {
        System.out.println(date.toISOString() + ", " + date.dayOfWeek());
    }

    return dates;
}
```

and the outputs are:

```
2013-01-01, Tuesday
2013-01-02, Wednesday
2013-01-03, Thursday
...
```